# Unable to cast object of type 'SystemDBNull' Error when using typed dataset

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I am trying out typed datasets (in a webform). However I get the error:

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."
```

and the Source Error:

```
Line 718:                get {
Line 719:                    try {
Line 720:                        return ((string)(this[this.tableCustomers.ContactNameColumn]));
Line 721:                    }
Line 722:                    catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) {
```

My code as follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet1TableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter cusAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter();
            DataSet1.CustomersDataTable customersDataTable = new DataSet1.CustomersDataTable();
            cusAdapter.Fill(customersDataTable);

            Session["CustomerDataTable"] = customersDataTable;

            GridView1.DataSource = from x in customersDataTable select new { x.ContactName, x.ContactTitle };
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

Comment: this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25860241/578411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you the exact problem.

You are trying to cast a null column to a string.

If you are using `DataTable/DataRow` then you can just use the extension `.Field<string>("Column Name")`

or do `string result = value == DBNull?null:(string) value;`

Comment: Could you please show how to use the extension way (`.Field`) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The TypedDataset generates a helper method for each field allowing you to check if its value is DbNull. In your case you can use them as follows, assuming ContactTitle is nullable as well:

```
GridView1.DataSource = from x in customersDataTable 
    select new { 
        ContactName = x.IsContactNameNull() ? "<no name>" : x.ContactName, 
        ContactTitle = x.IsContactTitleNull() ? "<no title>" : x.ContactTitle
    };
```